# Looping and scanning a list of e.g., 200 strings against a column with string data (Excel, VBA, Macros)

Tags: excel, vba

To the best of my efforts (VBA novice) I have been trying to write using stack and other resources a macro which would allow me to scan a given list of strings in excel against another much larger list for possible partial matches (Vlookup seems not to do a trick and Instr is a lot better for this it seems). I have been able to get some code working which leverages a loop to scan through a specific range and look for a single string of interest. For example let's say I have 20 cells in Column C with various names of fruits and vegetables and I would like to highlight only specifc ones of interest for me. In the code's case below I have included a string "Cher" (for Cherry) to be searched for against the range which if found creates a hit to the right of the column searched.

My major question would be how to adjust the code so that I could not only search for a single string like "Cherry", but how to run it against a very long list e.g. of 200 items when dealing with a couple of thousands of rows of data?

```
Sub listchecker()

    Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Range("C2:C20")
            If InStr(cell.Value, "Cher") > 0 Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell

    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for anyone's help!

Thank you NautMeg and SRJ for the suggestions below. I did adjust the code and it seems to be working now against an array as noted below (hooray)

```
Dim wordsArray() As Variant
wordsArray = Worksheets("Keywords").Range("B2:B439").Value
Dim word As Variant


  Dim cell As Range
       For Each cell In Worksheets("Normalized").Range("J2:J49010")
           For Each word In wordsArray
               If InStr(cell.Value, word) > 0 Then
                   cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Value
               End If
           Next word
       Next cell
```

The only thing I realized now though is that it would be better for 'cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Value' actually to populate with the array match (the keyword) rather than the cell's value. This is because the keyword might be too broad or too generic and result in false positives. Returning the cells value instead of the match from the array makes life more difficult to troubleshoot/identify a bad broad/generic keyword e.g., ("is").

Comment: Store them in an array? `array("cher","app",... etc)` and loop through it, but using `Find` would obviate the need for a second loop. The array could be populated from the sheet or just loop the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as SJR mentions above you could store the 200 search items in an array and then amend your code to something like the following:

```
    Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Range("C2:C20")
            '// Add Another For Loop here to loop through your words array 
            For Each wrd in wordsArray
                If InStr(cell.Value, wrd) > 0 Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
                End If
            Next word
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Possible issue with this kind of search is that it will pick up the first match, for example a search for "mang" could turn up "mango" or "mangetout" depending on which item comes up in the list first. This may or may not be desirable but something to look out for.

Comment: Thank you NautMeg and SRJ for the suggestions. I did adjust the code and it seems to be working now against an array as noted below

Comment: That's fine. To return the array  entry rather than the cell value simply amend the code as follows: `cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Value` needs to be changed to `cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = word`