# Scanning through lists in VBA and adding each hit in the same cell

Tags: vba

I have been leveraging for the past several months a couple of lines of code in VBA which with the help of the stackoverflow community I was able to adjust as needed (link [Looping and scanning a list of e.g., 200 strings against a column with string data (Excel, VBA, Macros)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285010/looping-and-scanning-a-list-of-e-g-200-strings-against-a-column-with-string-da)). Essentially, the code scans row by row through a list of pre-defined keywords against a range of data highlighting possible hits in an adjacent empty column/cell. For example, if my range/column contained "DOG ABC LLC" and my keyword list/array contained "ABC" the macro helped easily highlight the hit in another column by displaying it.

I have noticed one issue with this method that often more than one keyword hit could occur. For example, I can have an array containing both "ABC" and "DOG" as separate keywords. The current loop in place sadly only factors in the first hit apparently and then moves on. I was wondering whether there is an easy way of adjusting the code so that one could add all possible hits into a cell after a comma or space. Therefore instead of seeing just "DOG" or "ABC", one could clearly see that there were 2 hits "ABC , DOG". Here is the code I have been using thus far:

```
 Dim wordsArray() As Variant
 wordsArray = Worksheets("Keywords").Range("B2:B439").Value
 Dim word As Variant
 Dim cell As Range
       For Each cell In Worksheets("Normalized").Range("J2:J49010")
           For Each word In wordsArray
               If InStr(cell.Value, word) > 0 Then
                   cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = word
               End If
           Next word
       Next cell
```

Thank you in advance for advice!

Comment: Instead of just putting the result in the adjacent cell you could concatenate each match into a string and put that into the cell at the end of your `word` loop.

Comment: Also, as you have quite a lot of data, it would be quicker to write to arrays rather than on the sheet.